# シェルスクリプトでの文字列の整形

Tags: linux, bash

次のようなデーターがあります。
これを次のような条件でシェルスクリプトを用いて変換したいです

①一つ前の行に「&nbsp ;」がない数字は「--」をつける
②ない場合はなにもつけない

```
06
&nbsp;
26
&nbsp;
56
07
&nbsp;
26
&nbsp;
54
08
&nbsp;
27
&nbsp;
55
10
&nbsp;
01
11
&nbsp;
01
12
&nbsp;
01
13
&nbsp;
01
&nbsp;
52
14
&nbsp;
52
```

つまり、先程のものをこのように変更したいです。

```
-06-
26
56
-07-
26
54
-08-
27
55
-10-
01
-11-
01
-12-
01
-13-
01
52
-14-
52
```

自分でもsedやtrを使って試行錯誤してみたのですがうまく行きませんでした。よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 皆様解答ありがとうございました。より簡潔だったのでこちらをBAにしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input.txt にテキストがあるとして、

```
cat input.txt | sed -ne '/&nbsp;/{n; p; d;}; s/^\(.*\)$/-\1-/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

以下のようなスクリプトを作成し、

```
#!/bin/bash

nbsp=false
while read line; do
    if [ "${line}" == "&nbsp;" ]; then
        nbsp=true
    else
        if "${nbsp}"; then
            echo "${line}"
        else
            echo "-${line}-"
        fi
        nbsp=false
    fi
done
```

`cat test_data.txt | bash script.sh` のように標準入力から与えることで希望の出力を得られました。

コメントとして、1行前の状態を元に処理する必要があるため、`sed`などを利用して1行ずつ処理するよりも繰り返しの方が簡単に記述できる場合が多いです。